# Widget Slider e flutter_staggered_grid_view Slider

Tags: flutter, dart, slider

Como fazer para individualizar as ações desses Widget Slides?

O problema é que quando eu deslizo um, o outro também reage como se fosse um clone.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando o exemplo da biblioteca "flutter_staggered_grid_view Slider 3.0".

home.dart.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:my_blynk_2_socke_reiniciu_2_ghit_hub/bloc/slider_bloc.dart';
import 'package:my_blynk_2_socke_reiniciu_2_ghit_hub/model.dart';
import 'package:my_blynk_2_socke_reiniciu_2_ghit_hub/slider_V0.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  WebSocketChannel channel;
  SliderBloc bloc = new SliderBloc();
  final List<String> listA = [];

  FutureBuilder<List<HitsArrayImage>> futureBuilder;

  int _counter = 0;

// Dados variavel recebe jsonString no get dado
  var values;
//--------------------------------------------------------

  String pegaVlSlidServidEnviSlid;
  var sendGargSliderBloc;
  var snapshotDados;

//--------------------------------------------------------
  ///  Variaveis Texto do Container
  String recTextContaine;

  ///
//--------------------------------------------------------
  var timer;
  Timer imer;
  bool isStopped = false;
//--------------------------------------------------------
  double writDoubleValue;
//--------------------------------------------------------
  ///
  Future<List<HitsArrayImage>> _getDado() async {
    final response =
        await http.get('http://192.168.xxx.xxx:0000/chm_pin_d/posts');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      values = hitsArrayFromJsonImage(response.body);
      return values;
    } else {
      return null;
      //throw Exception('Falha ao carregar um post');
    }
  }

  ///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ///
  sec5Timer() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
      if (isStopped) {
        timer.cancel();
      }
      print("Dekhi 5 sec ");
    });
  }

  ///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  addDoubleToSF(id, writDoubleValue) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setDouble(
      'writDoubleValue',
      writDoubleValue,
    );
    prefs.setString(
      'id',
      id,
    );
  }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ///
  @override
  void dispose() {
    channel.sink.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  ///
  @override
  void initState() {
    channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
        'ws://192.168.xxxxxx:0000/auth_token/slider/value');
    super.initState();
  }

  ///
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Recosntruindo Builder...... ");
    return Scaffold(
        drawer: Drawer(),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            CustomScrollView(
              slivers: <Widget>[
                //custom scroll behaviour for appbar
                SliverAppBar(
                  iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.blue),
                  floating: true,
                  snap: true,
                  //seethrough
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  //shadow
                  elevation: 0.0,
                  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    title: StreamBuilder(
                        stream: bloc.output,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          snapshotDados = snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data : 1;
                          print(snapshotDados);
                          return Text(
                            snapshot.hasData ? '${snapshot.data}' : 'valor',
                            //"Automação",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 26.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          );
                        }),
                  ),
                  centerTitle: true,
                ),

                ///
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                ///    FutureBuilder
                FutureBuilder<List<HitsArrayImage>>(
                    future: _getDado(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.hasError) {
                        return SliverToBoxAdapter(
                          child: Container(
                            height: 200.0,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                              valueColor:
                                  AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.orange),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return SliverStaggeredGrid.count(
                          crossAxisCount: 8,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 0, //1.0,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 0, //1.0,
                          staggeredTiles: snapshot.data.map((doc) {
                            return StaggeredTile.count(doc.x, doc.y);
                          }).toList(),

                          ///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                          ///
                          children: snapshot.data.map((doc) {
                            return Container(
                              child: Card(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 255),
                                child: InkWell(
                                    onTap: () {},
                                    child: Stack(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        ///
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                        ///   Title
                                        Visibility(
                                          visible: doc
                                              .flagTextTitle, // == true ? true : false,
                                          child: Positioned(
                                            child: Container(
                                              child: Column(
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  Padding(
                                                    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(
                                                        doc.padding),
                                                    child: Center(
                                                      child:
                                                          Text(doc.titleFora),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  SizedBox(
                                                    height: 5.0,
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                        ///  SLIDER... 1
                                        Visibility(
                                          child: StreamBuilder(
                                              stream: bloc.output,
                                              //initialData: doc.setChangedSlider,
                                              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                                print(snapshot.data);
                                                return widgetSliderV0(
                                                    doc.sId,
                                                    doc.flagSet,
                                                    doc.setChangedSlider0,
                                                    snapshotDados,
                                                    bloc.newRatingRetorno,
                                                    snapshot.data,
                                                    onClickActionV0:
                                                        (newRatingRetorno) {
                                                  {
                                                    addDoubleToSF(doc.sId,
                                                        newRatingRetorno);
                                                    channel.sink.add(
                                                        '$newRatingRetorno');
                                                    bloc.setSliderBloc0(
                                                        newRatingRetorno);
                                                  }
                                                });
                                              }),
                                        ),

                                        ///
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                        ///
                                      ],
                                    )),
                              ),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        );
                      }
                    })
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

slider_V0.dart.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

var textButtOnD;
var textButtOfD;
var titleForaD;
var posD;
var xD;
var yD;
var aD;
var rD;
var gD;
var bD;
String namePinD;
String nameModD;
var setChangedSliderD;
var flagSetD;
String flagSetNameD;
var flagSetCores;
var buttSizWidtD;
var buttSizHeigD;
var colorButD;
var colorContD;
var flagTextTitleD;
var flagButtD;
var flagSlidD;
var flagSlidBD;
var flagLedD;
//
// **********************************************************************************

bool flagSliderAqui = false;
var _valueA = 0.0;
var _valueB;
bool flagSlidVl = false;
var setsnapshotdata;

var setValorSlider; // = 1.0;

double writDoubleValue;
double readDoubleValue;
var readDoubleid;



Container widgetSliderV0(
  sIdJsonString,
  flagSet,
  setChangedSlider,
  snapshotDados,
  newRatingRetorno, 
  snapshotdata,

  {
  Function onClickActionV0,
}) {
 
        

  return Container(
    color: Colors.orange[50],
    child: Row(

        children: [
          Icon(
            Icons.ac_unit,
            size: 30,
          ),
          Expanded(
             child: Slider(
             
              value: setValorSlider, 
              min: 1,
              max: 250,
              activeColor: Colors.red,
              inactiveColor: Colors.blue,
              label: 'Set a value', 
              onChanged: (double newValue) {
                _valueA = newValue; 
                onClickActionV0(_valueA);
              },

              onChangeEnd: (double newValue) {
              _makePutRequest(sIdJsonString, newValue);
              }

            ),
       ),
    ]),
  );

}

// ======================   PUT    ==========================================================
//
const Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"};
  _makePutRequest(sIdJsonString, setChangedSliderD) async {

  String jsonputi = jsonEncode({
    "setChangedSlider": setChangedSliderD,
  });

  String url = '${'http://192.168.xxx.xxx:0000/chm_pin_d/update/setslider/'}' +
      sIdJsonString;
 
  Response response = await put(url, headers: headers, body: jsonputi);
  int statusCode = response.statusCode;
  String body = response.body;
  print('Status: $statusCode, $body');
}
```

json

```
{
"valueSliderArray": [],
"color": [
250,
250,
250,
250
],
"colorBut": [
255,
38,
42,
45
],
"colorCont": [
255,
38,
42,
45
],
"textColor": [
"254",
"254",
"254",
"254"
],
"splashColor": [
"240",
"240",
"240",
"240"
],
"_id": "5e794ffe40d78f0764b808c5",
"image": "",
"pos": 0,
"titleFora": "Nam",
"fontSize": 9.4,
"textButtOn": "ON",
"textButtOf": "OFF",
"x": 4,
"y": 1,
"a": 255,
"r": 38,
"g": 42,
"b": 45,
"namePin": "V0",
"nameMod": "Mod",
"flagSetName": "ON",
"flagSet": "0",
"setChangedSlider0": 53.873965170047704,
"flagSetCores": 0,
"flag_text_title": false,
"flagButtTooglePush": false,
"flag_butt": false,
"flag_slid": false,
"flag_slid_b": true,
"flag_led": false,
"typea": "Container",
"alignment": "center",
"typeb": "RaisedButton",
"padding": 1.1,
"elevation": 8.2,
"click_event": "route://productDetail?goods_id=120",
"typec": "Text",
"data": "But D1",
"__v": 0,
"valueA": 55.455
},
{
"valueSliderArray": [],
"color": [
250,
250,
250,
250
],
"colorBut": [
255,
38,
42,
45
],
"colorCont": [
255,
38,
42,
45
],
"textColor": [
"254",
"254",
"254",
"254"
],
"splashColor": [
"240",
"240",
"240",
"240"
],
"_id": "5e79500240d78f0764b808c6",
"image": "",
"pos": 0,
"titleFora": "Nam",
"fontSize": 9.4,
"textButtOn": "ON",
"textButtOf": "OFF",
"x": 4,
"y": 1,
"a": 255,
"r": 38,
"g": 42,
"b": 45,
"namePin": "V1",
"nameMod": "Mod",
"flagSetName": "ON",
"flagSet": "0",
"flagSetCores": 0,
"flag_text_title": false,
"flagButtTooglePush": false,
"flag_butt": false,
"flag_slid": false,
"flag_slid_b": true,
"flag_led": false,
"typea": "Container",
"alignment": "center",
"typeb": "RaisedButton",
"padding": 1.1,
"elevation": 8.2,
"click_event": "route://productDetail?goods_id=120",
"typec": "Text",
"data": "But D1",
"__v": 0,
"valueB": 12.55,
"setChangedSlider0": 152.12037123359093
},
{
"valueSliderArray": [],
"color": [
250,
250,
250,
250
],
"colorBut": [
255,
38,
42,
45
],
"colorCont": [
255,
38,
42,
45
],
"textColor": [
"254",
"254",
"254",
"254"
],
"splashColor": [
"240",
"240",
"240",
"240"
],
"_id": "5e7d24af7486c046f0b53191",
"image": "",
"pos": 0,
"titleFora": "Nam",
"fontSize": 9.4,
"textButtOn": "ON",
"textButtOf": "OFF",
"x": 4,
"y": 1,
"a": 255,
"r": 38,
"g": 42,
"b": 45,
"namePin": "V1",
"nameMod": "Mod",
"flagSetName": "ON",
"flagSet": "0",
"flagSetCores": 0,
"flag_text_title": false,
"flagButtTooglePush": false,
"flag_butt": false,
"flag_slid": false,
"flag_slid_b": true,
"flag_led": false,
"typea": "Container",
"alignment": "center",
"typeb": "RaisedButton",
"padding": 1.1,
"elevation": 8.2,
"click_event": "route://productDetail?goods_id=120",
"typec": "Text",
"data": "But D1",
"__v": 0,
"valueB": 12.55,
"setChangedSlider0": 152.12037123359093
}
]
```

Estou criando um app para tomação residencial que vai conter muitos Slides.
Coloquei um código enxuto mas já tentei de varias maneiras mas não to sendo capaz de resolver isso, agradeço toda ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu código está um pouco bagunçado e complicado de entender, então vou lhe dar um exemplo de como fazer e você aplica para o seu caso...

> 1º Crie um Widget para ser seu `CustomSlider`

```
class MySlider extends StatefulWidget {
  MySlider({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  double sliderValue = 0;

  @override
  _MySliderState createState() => _MySliderState();
}

class _MySliderState extends State<MySlider> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Slider(
      value: widget.sliderValue,
      onChanged: (double value){
        setState((){
          widget.sliderValue = value;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

*Obs: Ao invés de expor a propriedade `sliderValue` você pode passar parâmetros para o teu Widget, como vi que você já faz no seu fonte, assim tu passa para ele teu `Sink` do BLoC e ao invés de alimentar o `sliderValue` tu passa o valor direto para o `Sink`.*

> 2º Crie uma classe para armazenar seus `Sliders` e assim você ter um
>   controle melhor deles

```
class SliderController{
  SliderController({@required this.index, @required this.slider});
  int index;
  MySlider slider;
}
```

> 3º Implemente seus `CustomSlider`

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyWidget(){
    sliders.add(SliderController(index: 0, slider: MySlider()));
    sliders.add(SliderController(index: 1, slider: MySlider()));
    sliders.add(SliderController(index: 2, slider: MySlider()));
  }

  final List<SliderController> sliders = List<SliderController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            children: sliders.map((slider){
              return slider.slider;
            }).toList(),
          )
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Pegar valor do 2º slider"),
          onPressed: (){
            print(sliders[1].slider.sliderValue);
          }
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Explicação**

Fazendo dessa forma, você deixará que cada `CustomSlider` criado por você se "auto-controle" assim um não afetará o outro.
Outra coisa é que com uma lista desses Widgets você consegue fazer diversos controles que queira, pois terá tudo armazenado em um lugar.

Abaixo deixo o código completo que pode ser testado no [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/flutter) (Basta copiar o código e colar lá)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyWidget(){
    sliders.add(SliderController(index: 0, slider: MySlider()));
    sliders.add(SliderController(index: 1, slider: MySlider()));
    sliders.add(SliderController(index: 2, slider: MySlider()));
  }

  final List<SliderController> sliders = List<SliderController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            children: sliders.map((slider){
              return slider.slider;
            }).toList(),
          )
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Pegar valor do 2º slider"),
          onPressed: (){
            print(sliders[1].slider.sliderValue);
          }
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MySlider extends StatefulWidget {
  MySlider({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  double sliderValue = 0;

  @override
  _MySliderState createState() => _MySliderState();
}

class _MySliderState extends State<MySlider> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Slider(
      value: widget.sliderValue,
      onChanged: (double value){
        setState((){
          widget.sliderValue = value;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}

class SliderController{
  SliderController({@required this.index, @required this.slider});
  int index;
  MySlider slider;
}
```

Comment: Oi Matheus, fiz umas mudanças no código q você postou para adaptá-lo ao meu e agora os Sliders estão individualizados.  Não sei se o código esta correto pelo que pesquise parece não ser uma boa pratica passar parâmetros no "Construtor", mas foi a unica maneria que consegui. Atualizei o Link do Git na resposta a cima e atualizei o código com as mudanças e dei uma organizada, vlw a ajuda fiquei um bom tempo travado nessa questão e agora vou dar sequencia no meu prazeroso projeto de automação de um hobbista rs.

Comment: @mauroviana Por nada, fico feliz que lhe foi útil! E de forma alguma, passar parâmetros no construtor NÃO É uma má prática, fique tranquilo... Qualquer dúvida estamos aqui pra te ajudar, e tem meus contatos também no meu perfil.

Comment: @mauroviana se minha resposta resolveu este teu caso, favor marcá-la como aceita usando o perfil que você utilizou para fazer a pergunta.